# how to delete (photo ,video , file) in android 9

Tags: android

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        //Detects request codes
        if(requestCode==GET_FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            String path=textView.getText().toString();
            File file=new File(selectedImage.toString());

            boolean b= file.delete();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"  "+b+"   ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the toast display? is it a true or false?

Comment: Toast display false

Comment: What is the uri you getting for Selected Image?

Comment: i want to know how to delete any file

Comment: the problem is with your uri, Rest is all good

Comment: how can i solve this .

Comment: how can get the path of file

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, check whether if it works or not.
You have to pass uri.getPath() as the actual path of the image to generate the file.

```
  @Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

//Detects request codes
if(requestCode==GET_FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    String path=textView.getText().toString();
    File file=new File(selectedImage.getPath());
    if (file.exist() ) 
    {
       file.delete();
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Deleted Successfully" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   } else
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File not found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try {
        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: post the uri you getting for your file.